# One-Way Repeated Measures ANOVA & Simple Linear Regression SPSS - understanding Independent Variable

Tags: anova, spss

Research Question: A researcher wants to investigate the emotional experience of discrete emotion categories in children aged 7-11 (50 participants in total). To assess subjective emotional experience, participants watched a series of emotion eliciting film clips and then reported their subjective experience of a range of emotions on a scale from 0 (not at all) to 6 (very much). Subjective emotional experience was assessed for 3 emotions: happiness, anger & sadness.

Dependent variable = avg self reported experience of emotion. A higher score indicated more subjective emotional experience.

I am struggling to figure out what the independent value is. Is it the emotions or is it age?

Any help is appreciated!
[image: SPSS variable view]

Answer (score 0):

If you do a linear regression using one of the emotion variables as the dependent and Age as a predictor then Age would be the independent variable. If you use the three emotion variables as the levels of a within-subjects or repeated-measures ANOVA, then emotion type would be the independent variable. In the latter case, you'd go to Analyze>General Linear Model>Repeated Measures, and in the first dialog box, you'd specify 3 as the number of levels for the one within-subjects factor, and perhaps change the name from factor1 to EmotionType or something like that. After clicking Define, you'd move the three emotion variables into the slots on the right and for just the basic analysis, click OK.